# Replacing ',' characters in only odd positions

Tags: php, regex

I need replace ',' characters with regex in php, but only in odd positions

I have:

`{"phone","11975365654","name","John Doe","cpf","42076792864"}`

I want replace ',' to ':', but only the odd:

`{"phone":"11975365654","name":"John Doe","cpf":"42076792864"}`

I'm trying this regex:

`preg_replace('/,/', ':', $data)`

But it get all quotes and no only the odd.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why not explode by `'` and glue them together if the counter is odd?

Comment: I would also not try this with a regular expression. For instance, a comma may be used in a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple:

```php
preg_replace('/(("[a-z]+"),(".+?"))+/', '$2:$3', $a)
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks!

Comment: You can omit the outer capturing group and you don't have to repeat it as it will not repeat due to the comma in between which will not be matched. You might use a negated character class instead of the non greedy `.+?` Then in the replacement use `$1:$2` https://regex101.com/r/FLGEQS/1 Note that the answer does not take the leading `{` and trailing `}` into account.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than regex, this just converts the list to an array (using `str_getcsv()` to cope with the quotes).  Then loops every other item in the list, using that item as the key and the next item as the value.  This can then be `json_encoded()` to give the result...

```
$data = str_getcsv(trim($input, "{}"));
$output = [];
for ( $i=0, $k=count($data); $i < $k; $i+=2)   {
    $output[$data[$i]] = $data[$i+1];
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Nice with the sinlgle loop ++

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal to use regex for this task. Having said that, if you know that your input can be matched by a simple regex, this should do it :

```
$str = '{"phone","11975365654","name","John Doe","cpf","42076792864"}';
$result = preg_replace('/,(.*?(?:,|[^,]*$))/ms', ':\\1', $str);
```

This lenient to some extra characters but it will fail if any string contains commas

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/Qn4jpa/1/)

Comment: It seems to work, but this is a perfect illustration why regex is not very readable.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware agreed, regex is not the best way to tackle this problem in most cases but I like to give the OP the benefit of the doubt that they know if it is appropriate in their problem space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using standard PHP functions:

```
$input   = '{"phone","11975365654","name","John Doe","cpf","42076792864"}';
$dataIn  = str_getcsv(trim($input, '{}'));

$keys    = array_filter($dataIn, function ($key) { return !($key & 1); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); 
$values  = array_filter($dataIn, function ($key) { return $key & 1; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); 

$DataOut = array_combine($keys, $values);
$output  = json_encode($DataOut);

echo $output;
```

This code is a lot longer than using a regex, but it is probably easier to read and maintain in the long run. It can cope with commas in the values.

Comment: Perfect!  
  
This is what I needed!

Comment: What about performance? For example json_decode VS str_getcsv and 1 single foreach/loop instead 2 array_filter?

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho You're right about `array_filter()` but `json_decode()` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice) and loop while there are still elements in the array:

```
$str   = '{"phone","11975365654","name","John Doe","cpf","42076792864"}';
$data  = str_getcsv(trim($str, '{}'));
$result = array();

while(count($data)) {
    list($k, $v) = array_splice($data, 0, 2);
    $result[$k] = $v;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Output

```
{"phone":"11975365654","name":"John Doe","cpf":"42076792864"}
```